# Is there a simpler way how to update the name of a synonym in code?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have renamed a synonym. It is referenced thousands of times in the code. Is finding every single of these references and changing them  the only way how to update the synonym name in code? Or are there other ways?

Comment: Anything named explicitly in code must be changed explicitly - every occurence - in code. If your code is stored in an external repository you may have tools that would let you do a mass replacement. The point of using a synonym is to avoid situations like that - point the synonym to a new object so you don't have to change the code; at most you might have to recompile or do a quick "create or replace" to rebuild dependent objects.

Comment: I'd suggest you to revert what you've already done, i.e. rename that synonym back to its original name.

Comment: Why to rename the synonym? You might rename the object pointed to instead.

Comment: @Saxon because the synonym is interfering with Oracle functions due to its name